# "left out" or "missed out"

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I shared a document and realised that's not the correct version. A paragraph is missing from the document. Should I say

> 1. I have **missed out** a paragraph from the original content.
> 2. I have **left out** a paragraph from the original content.

Do they convey the same meaning in this context? Does *missed out* feel more unintentional than *left out*?

Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, "missed out" is not used in North American English

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: @gotube Thanks. For learning curiosity, what's the equivalent used in North American English?

Comment: "Left out" is probably the most common. I can't think of an expression that feels more accidental. "Omitted" is good too, but somewhat formal, and implies you intentionally left it out, while "left out" can be accidental. I'm curious what @OldBrixtonian has to say about how intentional "omitted" feels in UK English.

Comment: @gotube: I quite agree: "omit" is somewhat formal. It might sound a little unusual in an informal context. "Oops! I've omitted a paragraph" sounds unnatural to me. _Leave out_ and _omit_ seem to me equally intentional/accidental. I'll add a couple of references to my rather inadequate answer.

Comment: To clarify, "missed out" *can* be used in the US in other contexts, like "I *missed out* on tacos today because I had a meeting over lunch."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right. **Leave out** might mean you did it intentionally. **Miss out** (which, as *gotube* points out and Lexico confirms, is not used in the US) sounds the most accidental. This may be because the word *miss* on its own is so often associated with failure.

**[leave out](https://www.lexico.com/definition/leave_out):** Fail to include someone or something.
**[miss out](https://www.lexico.com/definition/miss_out):** [British] Fail to include someone or something; omit.
**[omit](https://www.lexico.com/definition/omit):** Leave out or exclude (someone or something), either intentionally or forgetfully.